# Binding OneWayToSource in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, data-binding, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm currently trying to receive the `DateTime` from a `Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker`.
I just want to populate the model which is a `DateTime pickerTime` variable.
This variable will be populated by whatever is in the TimePicker view.

Therefore I need to do OneWayToSource data binding but I only ever find examples in XAML, where as I'm working in C# file because its an Android custom render of a abstract Xamarin.Forms Page.

Is there any way to OneWayToSource data bind in C#? If not I would try making the Forms View page type of my abstract sub-classed page so I have access to a XAML page and make the TimePicker view as well the data bound object in there that the Custom Renderer Pages inherit with OneWayToSource data binding.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. Considering you have already set the `BindingContext`, this XAML:

```
<TimePicker x:Name="myTimePicker" Time="{Binding Property, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

is the same as this in C#:

```
TimePicker myTimePicker = new TimePicker();
myTimePicker.SetBinding(TimePicker.TimeProperty, new Binding("Property") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource });
```

FYI, anything you can do in XAML can be done using C#!

Comment: Looking online it seems that the TimeProperty is of type `TimeSpan`. Is there a way to get this to `DateTime` type?

Comment: Or rather will using the Ticks operation on the `TimeSpan` give me the time in milliseconds as a `long` since that is what I need in the end.

Comment: @BBest If you need the date and time, just go for a `DateTimePicker` control. It's easy to adapt this piece of code with your suitable control.

Comment: It's for gettin the time for an alarm so is it even necessary to get the date?

Comment: It really depends on your business needs. I.e. If a future implementation needs the ability to set up an alarm the following day/week/month instead of the current day. It's up to you!

Comment: Ahh good point, probably useful for repeating alarms on certain days